# Lodash map value of key to another key

Tags: javascript, lodash

Hi I am currently using map to grab values for specific keys of an array of objects like this:

```
this.inspection.diseases = _.map(inspection.diseases, ({ disease_type_id, name }) => ({ disease_type_id, name }));
```

Which is fine, but I need to map the value of disease_type_id to the id key. Any quick and clean way of doing this with lodash or JS for that matter?

Comment: I don't really understand, do you just want to rename the key? Like `=> ({ id: disease_type_id`?

Comment: So I want the value of disease_type_id to map to the id key

Comment: I think I have solved it thanks to @ASDFGerte pointing me in the right direction: _.map(inspection.diseases, ({ disease_type_id: id, name }) => ({ id, name }));

Comment: I would prefer renaming on the output and not the input of the function (for very minor readability reasons) but either way works, yes.